# "VariationActivationError: channelIds.map is not a function" When pushing theme files live in BigCommerce

Tags: javascript, html, function, bigcommerce

I'm trying to push my updated theme files for BigCommerce using a modified version of Cornerstone Light theme. I started getting an error that says:
`not ok -- VariationActivationError: channelIds.map is not a function`
and when I search my theme for `channelIds.map` or `channelIds` nothing comes up. I do have several entries for `channelId`.

I'm really not experienced enough to know what info I should provide that may help answer the issue... but here are the entries that contain the channelId.

global.js

```
const {
            channelId, cartId, productId, categoryId, secureBaseUrl, maintenanceModeSettings, adminBarLanguage, showAdminBar,
        } = this.context;

...

        if (showAdminBar) {
            adminBar(secureBaseUrl, channelId, maintenanceModeSettings, JSON.parse(adminBarLanguage), productId, categoryId);
        }
```

base.html

```
        {{~inject 'channelId' settings.channel_id}}
```

adminBar.js

```
 * @param channelId
export default function (secureBaseUrl, channelId = 1, maintenanceMode = {}, adminBarLanguage, productId, categoryId) {
```

Answer (score 1):

This was recently resolved! You will need to [upgrade the Cli](https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli) version
to v3.9.0 and try again. More information on this error and what was resolved can be found [here](https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/pull/849).